# Use zsh's global aliases inside argument

Tags: zsh

I use global aliases for some of my remote hosts like
`alias -g MY_HOST="server.waytolongfoobar.com"` to be able to ssh into them using `ssh MY_HOST`. But if I want to scp something to the host, I have to use something awkward like `scp file.tar.gz 'echo MY_HOST':~/dir`. Is there a nicer way to use global aliases inside arguments?

Maybe I use global aliases for the wrong purpose? I think I could actually use exported variables like `scp file $MY_HOST:~/dir`. What's the benefit of global aliases over variables anyway (beside not having to type the $).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, there is no good way to use an alias because it has to be an independent (space separated) token on the command line. Aliases can actually be less flexible than variables for that exact reason. The purpose of an alias is to save you typing. Global aliases are intended for files or other standalone expressions that you use very frequently. A host name is generally not standalone.

Answer (score 7):

You can define host aliases directly in `ssh` without using the shell. Add the following to your `.ssh/config` file:

```
host MY_HOST
    HostName server.waytolongfoobar.com
```

Now, any place where `ssh` or `scp` would take a host name, it will treat `MY_HOST` as a synonym for `server.waytolongfoobar.com`.

---

As to your question regarding the utility of aliases, they are expanded before any part of the command line is parsed, allowing you to include shell syntax:

```
% alias -g PAGE="| less"
% cat .zshrc PAGE         # expands to cat .zshrc | less
% alias -g ignore="> /dev/null"
% cat .zshrc ignore
```

Comment: Didn't know about this ssh feature. Thanks!

Comment: Aside from the fact that you do not mention much about the purpose of aliases, your answer is generally more useful than mine.